# trivial cohomology group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $A$ be a $G$-module and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Moreover, $H^i(N,A)=0$ for all $i=1, \dotsc, q-1$ and $q \geq 1$. Define 
$$ B:= A \otimes \mathbb{Z} [G ]. $$

The claim is that $B$ is cohomologically trivial on $G$, i.e. $H^q(G, B)=0$ and that also $B^N$ is cohomologically trivial on $G/N$, i.e. $H^q(G/N, B^N)$.

Without further explanation, we used these statements in a proof. Unfortunately, I fail to see why these hold. It would be of great help if anyone could explain this to me! Thank you!